# Can't encode csv file opened through paramiko as utf-8-sig to remove BOM using Python

Tags: python, csv, paramiko, byte-order-mark

I'm having issues reading a csv file that's opened through sftp using paramiko because the first field contains the BOM ï»¿ at the beginning. From what I've read, encoding as utf-8-sig will fix this, but I'm not able to figure-out how to encode this properly when using ssh_client of paramiko.

How would you encode after opening the file from SFTP? I'm using csv.Dictreader to read the file.

```
with ssh_client.open_sftp() as sftp_client:
    with sftp_client.file(newFileName)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paramiko `SFTPFile` does not support encoding configuration (though for some purposes, like `readline[s]`, it treats the file as UTF-8).

But you should be able to skip the BOM yourself:

```
with sftp_client.file(newFileName) as f:
    f.seek(0, 3)
    reader = csv.reader(f)
```